# multitimeframa MA cross over

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I am not a coder and knows only basic, If someone can help me, I have created an indicator that give multitimeframe data od 21ema and 8ema.
Problem 1 = when viewing on lower timeframe like 1 min the indicator work perfect, but when I view in 10min or 15min timeframe all the lower timeframe values are coming false.
Problem 2 = I need to add buy/sell signal depending on crossover of both the emas on multitimeframe. my current table according to script only shows buy sell signal depending upon price is above/below emas but I need buy/sell signal depending upon the cross over of both the emas.

```
//@version=5
indicator("MultiTime Buy/sell", overlay=true)



emaPeriod = input(8, "EMA Period")
emaPeriod2 = input(21, "EMA Period")
atrPeriod = input(5, "ATR Period")
supertrendFactor = input(1.2, "Supertrend Factor")

tableAlignment = input.string(position.top_right)

getValueForTime(timeStr, expr) =>
    request.security(syminfo.ticker, timeStr, expr) 

getValueForTime1(timeStr1, expr1) =>
    request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.ticker), timeStr1, expr1) 

getColor(value) =>
    color.from_gradient(value, 0, 100, color.rgb(0, 255, 0), color.rgb(255, 0, 0))

getColor1(value1) =>
    color.from_gradient(value1, 0, 100, color.rgb(0, 255, 0), color.rgb(255, 0, 0))

var indicatorTable = table.new(position = tableAlignment, columns = 10, rows = 4, bgcolor = color.rgb(0,0,0, 50), border_width = 1)


table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 0, row = 1,  text = "ALGO", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 0, row = 2,  text = "EMA (" + str.tostring(emaPeriod) + ")", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 0, row = 3,  text = "EMA (" + str.tostring(emaPeriod2) + ")", text_color = color.white)

table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 1, row = 0,  text = "1m", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 2, row = 0,  text = "2m", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 3, row = 0,  text = "5m", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 4, row = 0,  text = "10m", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 5, row = 0,  text = "15m", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 6, row = 0,  text = "30m", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 7, row = 0,  text = "1hr", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 8, row = 0,  text = "195m", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = 9, row = 0,  text = "Daily", text_color = color.white)

makeTableCell(column, row, bgColor, cellText) =>
    table.cell(table_id = indicatorTable, column = column, row = row,  text = cellText, bgcolor = bgColor, text_color = color.white)

makeRow(row, bgcolors, cellTexts) =>
    for int i = 0 to 8
        makeTableCell(1 + i, row, array.get(bgcolors, i), array.get(cellTexts, i))

fillArrayWithTime(timeStr, expr, mode, cellTexts, bgColors) =>
    value = getValueForTime(timeStr, expr)
    
    if (mode == "float")
        array.push(bgColors, getColor(value))
        array.push(cellTexts, str.tostring(math.round(value, 2)))
    else if (mode == "signal")
        array.push(bgColors, getColor(value == 1 ? 100 : value == -1 ? 0 : 50))
        array.push(cellTexts, value == -1 ? "Buy" : value == 1 ? "Sell" : "Neutral")
    [cellTexts, bgColors]

makeMultitimeIndicatorArray(expr, mode) =>
    cellTexts = array.new_string(0, "")
    bgColors = array.new_color(0, color.black)
    
    fillArrayWithTime("1", expr, mode, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime("2", expr, mode, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime("5", expr, mode, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime("10", expr, mode, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime("15", expr, mode, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime("30", expr, mode, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime("60", expr, mode, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime("195", expr, mode, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime("1D", expr, mode, cellTexts, bgColors)
    
    [cellTexts, bgColors]
    
fillArrayWithTime1(timeStr1, expr1, mode1, cellTexts, bgColors) =>
    value1 = getValueForTime1(timeStr1, expr1)
    
    if (mode1 == "float")
        array.push(bgColors, getColor1(value1))
        array.push(cellTexts, str.tostring(math.round(value1, 2)))
    else if (mode1 == "signal")
        array.push(bgColors, getColor1(value1 == 1 ? 100 : value1 == -1 ? 0 : 50))
        array.push(cellTexts, value1 == -1 ? "Buy" : value1 == 1 ? "Sell" : "Neutral")
    [cellTexts, bgColors]

makeMultitimeIndicatorArray1(expr1, mode1) =>
    cellTexts = array.new_string(0, "")
    bgColors = array.new_color(0, color.black)
    
    fillArrayWithTime1("1", expr1, mode1, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime1("2", expr1, mode1, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime1("5", expr1, mode1, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime1("10", expr1, mode1, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime1("15", expr1, mode1, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime1("30", expr1, mode1, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime1("60", expr1, mode1, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime1("195", expr1, mode1, cellTexts, bgColors)
    fillArrayWithTime1("1D", expr1, mode1, cellTexts, bgColors)
    

supertrendDirection() =>
    [supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(supertrendFactor, atrPeriod)
    direction

[supertrendTexts, supertrendBgColors] = makeMultitimeIndicatorArray1(supertrendDirection(), "signal")
[maTrendTexts, maTrendBgColors] = makeMultitimeIndicatorArray(ta.ema(close, 8) > close ? 1 : -1, "signal")
[maTrendTexts1, maTrendBgColors1] = makeMultitimeIndicatorArray(ta.ema(close, 21) > close ? 1 : -1, "signal")


makeRow(1, supertrendBgColors, supertrendTexts)
makeRow(2, maTrendBgColors, maTrendTexts)
makeRow(3, maTrendBgColors1, maTrendTexts1)
```

How to add crossover signal of buy and sell.
How to solve the issue of lower timeframe false data when viewing higher timeframe.

Comment: a few issues, heiken ashi is synthetic - it means that it will repaint and you will get flags which are not consistent with real time. Second, if your chart is in a higher timeframe(say 15min) and you are looking for lower tf information (say 5min) then the proper way to do this is to use request.security_lower_tf - the documentation explains how and why

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried using request.security_lower_tf but not working, when I do that the script will not run and will display error

Comment: i would need to see the script to help any further

Comment: Hey John, I have posted the script. I don't know if you can see it or not. Thanks

Comment: Nitin i am not seeing the source with request.security_lower_tf

Comment: I tried and solved the lower time frame issue, can you please guide me how to put a check box in the script, like the table include supertrend, 8ema and 21ema, but if at some point I only want to see 8 ema and nothing else or vice-versa how to do that? Thank you

Comment: it is a simple bool, `see_21ema= input.bool(true,"see 21 ema")`  then add the condition to the plot,  `plot(see_21ema? ema_21:na)`

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you guide me in this, I wiuld like to use this in day trading and swing trading, but input values are different for swing trading. How to add check box that changes value of input when I need to use it for swing trading

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create check boxes that change what is displayed.

```
    see_8ema = input.bool(false,"show 8 ema")
    ema_21= ta.ema(close,21)
    ema_8 = ta.ema(close,8)
    plot(see_21ema? ema_21:na, color=color.white,title="21 Ema")
    plot(see_8ema? ema_8:na, color=color.orange, title="8 Ema")
```

Comment: Thank you for you input, but my script does not plot ema, it gives a buy sell signal in a table format. Sorry I am not an expert coder so don't know how to use your idea in  the script. I want checkbox to have option whether to display 8 ema values in table or not. Sorry if I am annoying

Comment: for a box it is the same logic, if see_21ema is checked then display the  value in the box/cell, if not then display a blank character